# Achievement progression through events

Tags: pubg-battlegrounds

Very often on PUBG are various events, I just want to know if achievement as 10 crossbow kills count too from event games or only from normal games.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only progress your achievements from normal mode, not events or custom matches. The first one or two events actually allowed you to progress achievements like the solo chicken dinner achievement for winning the 8-man squad mode but that was an error.